# RL Algorithm successfully played openai gym CartPole-v1, but fails on atari Boxing-ram-v0

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

I recently implemented the ppo algorithm
He works well at CartPole-v1
But it does not work in Boxing-ram-v0
Can someone explain?

[this is my repo](https://github.com/skywalker0803r/reinforcement-learning-platform/blob/master/notebook/PPO.ipynb?fbclid=IwAR1W5a1mUkdw9yUhf3mux3_yAx75_eL3WjeoQatFFvTVhvCTHW8rt7JjWgc)

[this is the train score history in CartPole-v1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYGRn.png)

[and behavior in Boxing-ram-v0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUlLi.gif)

Can someone explain?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your model is that the agent actions are almost the same for all time steps. This is probably because of the neural networks getting saturated. In the CartPole environment, the states are in the range [-,1,1] for all dimensions but not in the Boxing-ram-v0 environment. So you should maybe normalise the states to the range [-1,1], before storing them in the buffer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you so i need to define a normalise function to preprocessing the observation?

Comment: Yes. Normalise them in the range [-1,1]